# Why create _rev field in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

When create database in couch db, and then create a new document then automatically create default _id field and _rev field. I know about _id which is unique but i don't know about _rev field and its work.

Comment: It is really well documented as an MVCC system. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API

Answer (score 10):

CouchDB uses Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC), and the `_rev` field holds this `MVCC` token which is used for optimistic-concurrency detection.

I recommend that you read more about it (as previously pointed out in comment by @WiredPrairie) or here: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/consistency.html#locking